# Why is this Fermata over a double bar line?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, double-bass, fermata

I'm currently studying Hrabe's 86 Etudes for String Bass. On Etude #3 I came upon this fermata:

[image: Example of a fermata over a double bar line]

It's not on top of any note or rest, but on a double bar line. How am I supposed to play this? Do I hold the last note, or is there a pause before I go on to the next line?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a way to say 'hang on a bit before you play the next bit'. There's no rest to put it on, and if it was over a note, that'd have to be held on.

---

P.S. What's the strange sign instead of a number at the start of the last bar?

Comment: It's the string playing symbol for "stop the string with your thumb,"  used on both cello and bass. 0 without the tick means "open string," or sometimes "natural harmonic".

Comment: If you had attached an image of the whole etude (only 4 lines) it would have been clear that this is the mid-point, and the second half is more or less the mirror image of the first half - so it means "take a short pause for breath." You can't easily show the *phrasing* using slurs in string parts, because they get confused with bowing instructions.

Comment: @alephzero - which hand thumb?

Comment: @Tim the fretting hand's thumb

Comment: @Tim left hand. You can't stop a string and use a bow with the same hand! See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIZtJvgUIsM for cello, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c-39Bten_E for bass.

Comment: @alephzero - there's no arco or pizzicato shown...

Answer (score 1):

It is usually the case, when you have multiple sections of a piece, one after the other, where the composer wants a slight pause in between sections. Remember Fermata just simply means pause.

Comment: A fermata does *not* mean "pause". It means "Keep doing what you're doing, longer than normally." That's why it can be put above both notes and rests. When put above a bar line, it means "Prolong the silence between the notes in the adjoining bars".

Comment: Both ABRSM and UNISA give the meaning of Fermata as a pause.

Comment: I suspect when they write "pause"  what they really mean is to pause the meter, not a "Grand Pause,"  which is a short pause where nobody plays.